# jqplot - Is it possible to set legend label text color in the chart's settings?

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot, textcolor

I have jqplot line charts and some pie charts.  I have been able to change everything except the text color of the legend labels.  It would be nice if I could make the label color match the swatch color but if I can just specify one color across the board that would be ok.

Additional info:
This link does what I need to unfortunately I don't think it will work for me, I have to do it in the chart options:
[Legend text color in accordance with line color in jqplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424471/legend-text-color-in-accordance-with-line-color-in-jqplot)

Here is exactly what I am trying to achieve in chart options but it doesn't appear to have a satisfactory answer:  [jqplot donut chart label/legend color and line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466989/jqplot-donut-chart-label-legend-color-and-line)

In the code below, in the legend definition, I set the background color and it works.  However, setting textColor does not.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if I can provide any more detail.

Thanks!!

> 

```js
grid:{
  background: '#2A2A2A',
  gridLineColor: '#FF9900'
},

seriesDefaults: {
   rendererOptions: {
      showDataLabels: true
   }
},

axes:{
  yaxis: {
    tickOptions: {
      textColor: '#FF9900'
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    tickOptions: {
      textColor: '#FF9900'
    },
    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
    ticks: dates,
    drawMajorGridlines: false
  }
},
  
series: [
  { label: 'Data1'},
  { label: 'Data2' },
  { label: 'Data3' },
  { label: 'Data4' }
],

legend: { 
  show: true, 
  location: 'e',
  background:'#FF9900'
}
```

Comment: Add the line of code which provide series colour of your legend .

Answer (score 0):

before all add this

```
seriesColors: [ "#F90E2A", "#10C40D", "#3886BB", "#F90E2A", "#ffffff", "#ffffff",
        "#ffffff", "#ffffff", "#ffffff", "#CDD6E0", "#ffffff"],
```

Comment: This is just the same code, did you forget to add the answer?

Comment: I added that code and the color of the lines and the swatches changes but not the text of the legend labels.

Comment: add screenshot so i can understand what is issue ?